# multi splice (or similar) to remove a number of objects in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

So i currently have 2 arrays:

```
const getUniqueRowErrors = [1,3]

const data = [
 {identifier: '000'},
 {identifier: '111'},
 {identifier: '222'},
 {identifier: '3333'},
 {identifier: '444'}
]
```

The idea is i want to remove the the elements based off the `getUniqueRowErrors`, so I want the 1st,and 3rd element removed from the the `data` array, so the end result being:

```
const data = [
 {identifier: '111'},
 {identifier: '3333'},
 {identifier: '444'}
]
```

I tried the following but the desired result is incorrect:

```
const filteredData = getUniqueRowErrors.map((rowToRemove) => data.splice(rowToRemove));
```

Any ideas how to do the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply filter by index and check if the index is in the row errors array:

```js
const getUniqueRowErrors = [1,3]

const data = [
 {identifier: '000'},
 {identifier: '111'},
 {identifier: '222'},
 {identifier: '3333'},
 {identifier: '444'}
];

console.log(data.filter((_, i) => !getUniqueRowErrors.includes(i + 1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const getUniqueRowErrors = new Set([1,3]);
const data = [
 {identifier: '000'},
 {identifier: '111'},
 {identifier: '222'},
 {identifier: '3333'},
 {identifier: '444'}
]
let res = data.filter((_, i) => !getUniqueRowErrors.has(i + 1));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a length to the splice method as the second parameter. In your case, you have to set it to 1. Also since you are not removing items based on the zero-indexed method, you have to subtract 1 from rowToRemove.

```js
data.splice(rowToRemove - 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getUniqueRowErrors = [1,3];

const data = [
 {identifier: '000'},
 {identifier: '111'},
 {identifier: '222'},
 {identifier: '3333'},
 {identifier: '444'}
];

const filteredData = data.filter((row, i) => !getUniqueRowErrors.includes(i + 1));
```

This returns a new array with the rows removed. Documentation on the filter function can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). The `.filter` removes any elements that don't pass the test provided. The `.includes` looks for the current index within the `getUniqueRowErrors` array and if found removes it due to the `!` at the start.